# Mocking repository class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, jdbctemplate

I want to test my repository layer class using JUnit and Mockito. Since I have lots of database tables I am not going to use an in-memory database to mock my database. I need to test the below method and it uses `JdbcTemplate` to retrieve data from the database.

```java
public List<EmployeeSqlDTO> findEmployees(String sqlQuery) {
    List<EmployeeSqlDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
    EmployeeSqlDTO sqlDTO;
    SqlRowSet rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sqlQuery, 1, 1);

    while (rowSet.next()) {
        sqlDTO = new EmployeeSqlDTO();
        sqlDTO.setId(rowSet.getInt("id"));
        sqlDTO.setName(rowSet.getString("name"));
        sqlDTO.setEmail(rowSet.getString("email"));
        list.add(sqlDTO);
    }
    return list;
}
```

`EmployeeSqlDTO` class contains three instance variables (`id`, `name`, `email`) with getters and setters.
I require to test the above method using Mockito and JUnit.
Is there a proper way to test the above code?

Comment: IMHO there is little value in unit testing this method. Most of the complexity is contained in the SQL query. And this part you can only verify by introducing an integration test.

Comment: What would you test? As @slauth already mentioned, the best way to test this is with an integration test.

Comment: "Since I have lots of database tables I am not going to use an in-memory database to mock my database" -> I don't understand this argument. What problems do you anticipate? Upvote for advice by @slauth

Comment: Additionally, better than using an in-memory database is using the database that you are acutally using in production. [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) does make this rather easy to setup.

Comment: I'd say if you want to unit test it then mock SqlRowSet and test that you populate DTO values correctly. Otherwise just integration test it.

Comment: @Lesiak In my entire project, I have many database tables. Here I only added one repository class method.

Comment: @TeamAurora Let me rephrase: why having multiple tables in the db is problematic? I strongly encourage you to take integration test path.  Mocking `jdbcTemplate` results in a lot of unmaintainable boilerplate, and, more importantly, won't detect real issues that may arise when querying the db: SQL syntax errors, wrong column types etc.